# True or false: if two matrices are simultatenously diagonalizable, they share an eigenbasis?

Tags: linear-algebra

So if this is true, and I wish to show that two matrices $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, I want to show that the eigenvalues of $A$ are also the eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: Nope, they share eigenvectors but not eigenvalues in general.

Comment: Also, it need not even be true that every eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $B$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Any example? That does not sound right to me...

Answer (score 1):

What about $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$?